# Changing two frames with one click worked , but going 'back' to only one of the frames

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to implement the change of two frames with one click with the help of the [tutorial](http://www.pageresource.com/html/frame4.htm). But one issue is there, that is  when I press the browser's Back button, it is not returning to the previous page, but instead will only change one of the frame back.

I have given my pages below ( except **page2.html**, **page3.html** and **page4.html** as they can be anything)

Could you please help me with a **Javascript** which will rectify this issue.

**Frameset**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<frameset rows="20%,80%">
<frame src="page1.html" name="top_frame">
<frame src="page2.html" name="bottom_frame">
</frameset>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Site</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function change2(url)
    {
    parent.bottom_frame.location=url;
    }
     </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    Click the link below to change both frames.
    <br />
    <a href="page4.html" target="top_frame" onclick=change2('page3.html')>change 2 frames</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't meant to troll, but dude it's 2013. There must be a better solution than using `<frameset>`...

Comment: what are you intending to do as if you see the example does the same thing and if you press the back button twice it goes back, basically the history is returning to the first change then on the second click returns the second change, do you want them both to change on one click of the back but? must also agree in a little with @BenM

Comment: @SimonDavies Exactly!,, I want them both to change on one click.  I just started webpage designing one month back and thats why I guess I am facing so many problems and I know only some basics of html .

Comment: then i would suggest looking into ajax and js/jQuery, rather than framesets, this would give you better control and do want you want to do a lot more easier.if got time might be able to do a test for you

Comment: Still struggling to find an answer for this question ... can any one pls give me a hand?